# how i can improve this sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
> | Id  | Number_Robot | image1 | image2 | image3 | image5 | image6 |
> ------------------------------------------------------------------               
> | 1   |     092155   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |   
> | 2   |      NULL    | 0kjjas | oknkn  | asda   | asdad  | aada   |   
> | 3   |      NULL    | dffggd | gdfgg  | gddgg  | NULL   | NULL   |   
> | 5   |     092155   | sddfw  | 34sdf  | dfgdg  | trdg   | NULL   |
```

By adding the following command, I added the column col_count to the table

```
select
    t1.image1,
    t1.image2,
    t1.image3,
    t1.image4,
    t1.image5,
    t1.image6,
    (
        select count(*)
        from (values (t1.image1), (t1.image2), (t1.image3), (t1.image4), (t1.image5), (t1.image6)) as v(col)
        where v.col is not null
    ) as col_count
from Tbl_Profile_pic as t1
```

And now my table is like this

```
   | Id  | Number_Robot | image1 | image2 | image3 | image5 | image6 | col_count |
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | 1   |    092155    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |    0      |
   | 2   |     NULL     | 0kjjas | oknkn  | asda   | asdad  | aada   |    5      |
   | 3   |     NULL     | dffggd | gdfgg  | gddgg  | NULL   | NULL   |    3      |
   | 5   |    092155    | sddfw  | 34sdf  | dfgdg  | trdg   | NULL   |    4
```

now , how i can select row col_count > 4 and Number_Robot is not Null ?

TNX

Comment: *"how i can improve this sql query?"* Ideally the real answer/solution should be including normalisation, as 6 column names exists  with incrementing numbers which are very good candicate for normalisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..
If your table is as final output mentioned then, further wrap it in `cte`, after that you can apply any filter using where clause as per your need.

```
; with cte as (
select
t1.image1,
t1.image2,
t1.image3,
t1.image4,
t1.image5,
t1.image6,
(
    select count(*)
    from (values (t1.image1), (t1.image2), (t1.image3), (t1.image4), (t1.image5), (t1.image6)) as v(col)
    where v.col is not null
) as col_count
from Tbl_Profile_pic as t1 )
select * from cte where col_count > 4 and Number_Robot is not Null
```

Comment: tnx @DarkRob :)

Comment: The colon at the beginning should be semicolon I believe?

Comment: @stickybit: ya it is typos.

Comment: @sticky-bit yes . Incorrect syntax near ':' , But it was enough for me ,TNX

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` instead of a subquery in the `SELECT`:

```
select t1.image1, t1.image2, t1.image3,
       t1.image4, t1.image5, t1.image6,
       v.col_count
from Tbl_Profile_pic t1 outer apply
     (select count(v.col) as col_count
      from (values (t1.image1), (t1.image2), (t1.image3), (t1.image4), (t1.image5), (t1.image6)
           ) as v(col)
     ) v
where v.col_count > 4 and Number_Robot is not null;
```

This also simplifies the subquery by using `count(<column>)` rather than using the `where` clause.